# Declaring an array with incremental values - is there a shortcut?

Tags: c#, wpf, arrays

This question is probably pretty stupid, but I'm new to C# and I'm not sure if there are any shortcuts to do this. I have a dynamic array for which the range will always be 1-n, with n being variable. Is there anyway to declare an array and have it hold incremental values without looping?

Think along the lines of my array holding values 1-50. I'd like to declare an array as such (logically): `double[] myArray = new double[] {1-50}` or, more generically for my purposes `double[] myArray = new double[] {1-n}`. I don't know what made me think of this, I just thought I'd ask.

I am going to bind this array (or list) to a combo box in WPF. I guess setting a combo-box the same way would also work if there's a shortcut for that.

Sorry for the dumb question. =)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
int n = 50;
var doubleArray = Enumerable.Range(1, n).Select(x => (double)x).ToArray();
```

That will generate a sequence of integers from 1 to n (in this case 50) and then cast each one to a `double` and create an array from those results.

Comment: there is another way to do this in a faster method?

Answer (score 3):

You could use a [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) which represents a dynamic array to which you could add elements.

Answer (score 0):

System.Linq.Enumerable.Range can generate än enumeration of int. Cast the enumeration if you really want double.

```
System.Linq.Enumerable.Range(1,20).ToArray()
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range.aspx